# Warning while loading the BertModel

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I load a BERT model using the following code snippet:

```
        name = "bert-base-uncased"

        from transformers import BertModel
        from transformers import BertTokenizer

        print("[ Using pretrained BERT embeddings ]")
        self.bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(name, do_lower_case=lower_case)
        self.bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained(name)
        if fix_emb:
            print("[ Fix BERT layers ]")
            self.bert_model.eval()
            for param in self.bert_model.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False
        else:
            print("[ Finetune BERT layers ]")
            self.bert_model.train()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Some weights of the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased were not used when initializing BertModel: ['cls.seq_relationship.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.bias', 'cls.predictions.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight', 'cls.predictions.decoder.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias']
- This IS expected if you are initializing BertModel from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing BertModel from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

These might help.

you're loading the bert-base-cased checkpoint (which is a checkpoint that was trained using a similar architecture to BertForPreTraining) in a BertForSequenceClassification model.

This means that:

```
The layers that BertForPreTraining has, but BertForSequenceClassification does not have will be discarded
The layers that BertForSequenceClassification has but BertForPreTraining does not have will be randomly initialized.
```

This is expected, and tells you that you won't have good performance with your BertForSequenceClassification model before you fine-tune it.